# What's "Databites" mean in heroku JawsDB MySQL Addons?

Tags: mysql, database, heroku

When I was try install JawsDB MySQL addon on Heroku I found Databites check-marked, I try to search what this expression mean But I can't get a good answer, Can any one know what this expression mean  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JawsDB recently went into general availability, separate from a heroku addon. From their website:

Databites

Once your database is listed with a status of ‘AVAILABLE’, the dashboard will allow you to create Databites. As a simple, yet powerful reporting tool, Databites provide users the ability to run basic (read-only) SQL queries against their provisioned database and save those queries for later execution. Once a Databite is created, it is saved to your dashboard where it can be re-run, edited, or deleted with ease.

On your dashboard, under the section labeled ‘Databites’, select “Create New Databite”. This will direct your browser to the Databite page where custom queries can be entered into the editor which features SQL syntax highlighting. Clicking “Update” underneath the editor will execute the query against your database and return the result set in the same browser window in a tabular format.

Using the “Back” link will return you to the dashboard where your Databite will now be listed in the Databite section. Clicking on an existing Databite will redirect the browser to the Databite page and re-execute the query.

For security reasons, Databites are read-only, i.e. they do not support statements that create database objects or that alter data in your database. Think of Databites as a way to create windows into the most important information stored in your database.